# Quarkus service does not expose a metrics endpoint with micrometer otlp

Tags: quarkus, metrics, open-telemetry, micrometer, open-telemetry-collector

I'm trying to find a way to exports traces and metrics from my Quarkus service to my open telemetry collector. Traces work fine following the Quarkus documentation. I cannot make metrics work, though. The main problem evolves from exchanging smallrye-metrics with **quarkus-micrometer-registry-otlp**.

I have configured this in my application.yaml:

```
    micrometer:
        export:
            otlp:
                enabled: true
                url: http://localhost:4317
```

I do not see any metrics being exported, though. Furthermore there is an issue that the new micrometer extension that Quarkus documentation suggests, does not expose a metrics endpoint (smallrye-metrics did this). Therefore I see a lot of
`"HTTP Request to /{myService}/metrics failed` when running the service in the cluster.
Does anyone have an idea how to make the micrometer metrics exporter work with the latest quarkus version and what I have to configure in order to have a metrics endpoint exposed again?
Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two separate issues here: The first one is that OTLP metrics are not exported. OTLP is a push-based protocol, so it will send metrics to the collector periodically.

The collector endpoint would be: `http://localhost:4317/v1/metrics` (maybe you are missing the `/v1/metrics` path there?).

As for the the failing requests to `/{myservice}/metrics`: It seems like some other service is trying to pull the metrics from your service. This is usually done when exporting the prometheus format (which is pull-based, i.e., the consumer is trying to get the metrics from the service instead of the service pushing the metrics).

I don't know your setup, but in general there are two ways of getting the data from the producer to the collector:

1. Use the OTLP exporter and push data to the collector, then figure out which service is trying to scrape the `/metrics` endpoint and turn that off or
2. Use the `micrometer-registry-prometheus`, which will create that `/metrics` endpoint and make the collector scrape the data. I think you would use the `prometheusreciever` on the collector to do that.

From my (very limited) checking of smallrye, it seems that they offer a Prometheus exporter, so your setup might already use a pull-based model. There would be some metrics consumer that is trying to get metrics from your service, leading to the failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

Using Quarkiverse's `quarkus-micrometer-registry-otlp` will push data using the OTLP protocol to an [OpenTelemetry Colector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/). There you can integrate to an end database.

The default `quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus`registry does expose a scraping endpoint at `/q/metrics/.

Please check: https://quarkus.io/guides/telemetry-micrometer